# entity framework navigation properties joins different sql produced from different applications

Tags: sql, entity-framework, join, navigation

In one web application I am using this :-

```
    using (MvcApplication1.Models.PlumSoftwareEntities db = new Models.PlumSoftwareEntities())
    {
       var results = (from p in db.Work_Details
                where p.CompanyID == 2
                select new { p.ID, p.Dated, p.Employee1.Abbrev, p.Activity.ActivityCode }).ToList();
    }
```

and it produces this SQL:-

```
    SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Dated] AS [Dated], 
    [Extent2].[Abbrev] AS [Abbrev], 
    [Extent3].[ActivityCode] AS [ActivityCode]
    FROM   [dbo].[Work Details] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Employee] = [Extent2].[ID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Activity] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[ActivityCodeID] = [Extent3].ActivityCodeID]
    WHERE 2 = [Extent1].[CompanyID]
```

in another web application I use exactly the same linq as above except it produces this SQL:-

```
    SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Dated] AS [Dated], 
    [Extent2].[Abbrev] AS [Abbrev], 
    [Extent3].[ActivityCode] AS [ActivityCode]
    FROM   [dbo].[Work Details] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Employees] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Employee] = [Extent2].[ID]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Activity] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[ActivityCodeID] = [Extent3].ActivityCodeID]
    WHERE 2 = [Extent1].[CompanyID]
```

the last navigation property is now a LEFT OUTER JOIN

what setting, explanation is there for this behaviour.

The connection strings are the same, to the same SQL server, with the same login, using the same Entity Framework 5 in both applications, both running ASP.NET 4.5

This is a simple example and the reason it matters to me about the left outer join is that I am projecting entity tables onto DTO objects using navigation properties caching these queries using SQlDependency. SQLDependency requires that all view must use INNER JOINS otherwise an error is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Solved Microsoft update KB2805227 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2805227) released May 2013 for .NET4.5 caused this issue for me. Uninstalling it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2805227 is all about keeping compatibility between .net Framework 4.5 and 4.0.  Once you apply it you get the SQL generated by the .Net FX 4.0.

The .net FX 4.5 behavior is the result of some performance optimizations and we encourage everyone to take advantage of it (just like you are doing). To opt in for this behavior after you apply the KB, you can set the targetFramework attribute of the httpRuntime element in your web.config file as follows:

```
 <system.web>
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Observe that setting this attribute might trigger other behavioral changes if your application was developed on .net framework 4.0.  For details about this attribute you can read this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx

Also, if your application was built with.net framework 4.0 you need to take extra steps to have NuGet include the correct version of the EntityFramework.dll assembly in your project for .net framework 4.5. The easiest way to do that is to update all packages by typing ‘Update-Package –Reinstall’ in the Package Manage Console.  If for some reason that doesn’t work for you or you want to avoid updating all packages, you can manually uninstall the EntityFramework package and all packages that depend on it (e.g. Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth) from your project and reinstall the EntityFramework package by typing ‘Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0’  and any dependent packages.